# Is there a way to add the workspace path to the Eclipse IDE title bar?

Tags: eclipse, workspace, titlebar

I sometimes run more than one eclipse with a new version of a project and another with an older version in a different workspace. Add an extra window view of the "new" version and it becomes difficult to tell when alt=tabbing which eclipse belongs to which workspace.

When a lot of files are involved with minor changes the only way to tell is to get the properties of a particular file and check the path. This of course is slow, there must be better way and having the workspace path in the title bar would make it easy to spot which instance is working with which workspace.

Is there a way to include the workspace path in the title bar so one can easily tell which workspace one is working with?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you add **`-showlocation`** in its own line at the beginning of your `eclipse.ini`, you will have the current workspace automatically displayed in the title bar.
(see this [example of `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590))

[image]

Answer (score 33):

If you go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace, there is an item "Workspace name (shown in window title):" that you can use. (I use Eclipse Helios CDT)

Comment: This is the best option if you work with multiple workspaces open in different instances of Eclipse because you can see the window title that you set from your taskbar or when you're alt-tabbing.

Comment: Perfect! You can set any custom name for the workspace and it shows right in the beginning of the title bar. This is better IMO as opposed to `-showlocation` that shows full path (could be too long) at the end of title.

Answer (score 5):

#### Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)

In [Eclipse Oxygen](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/) you can add the workspace path to the [configurable Window title](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#window-title).

1. **Window** > **Preferences**
2. **General** > **Workspace** > check **Show full workspace path**

   [image: General > Workspace > Show full workspace path]
3. Result:

   [image: Eclipse title bar]

#### Eclipse Neon (4.6) & Eclipse Mars (4.5)

The checkbox is in the same location, but it has a different text - **Show workspace path in window title**:

[image: Show workspace path]

Comment: Nice detailed answer, more up-to-date than my 7 years old answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

-showlocation is great, but it only changes the text at the end of the title bar, so it's often not visible in the taskbar.

If you want to change the beginning of the title bar, which shows the current Perspective, you can use Window -> Save Perspective As... and the new title will be visible in the Taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse-Mars I am seeing "Workspace Name" as an option that lets you type your custom workspace name, not sure in which version this was introduced but this option is available on the same location where @Oncra C pointed `(Window->Preferences->General->Workspace)`. 
The value you enter gets prepended to the start of the title.